# How can I remove duplicate result documents across Elasticsearch aggregation buckets?

Tags: elasticsearch, duplicates

Elasticsearch version 5.2.

I'm using a `top_hits` aggregation within a `filter` aggregation to get bucketed result sets that match different filters, but I don't want to see the same result in any two buckets, even if it matches both sets of filters. Is there a way to do this? Is it a bad idea?

Example query:

```
GET _search
{
"size": 0,
"aggs": {
    "block 1": {
        "filter": {
            "bool": {
                "must": [{
                        "terms": {
                            "property1": [
                                "value1",
                                "value2"
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "aggs": {
            "block 1_hits": {
                "top_hits": {
                    "size": 10
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "block 2": {
        "filter": {},
        "aggs": {
            "block 2_hits": {
                "top_hits": {
                    "size": 10
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: How many of these subquery "blocks" are we looking at here?  Under 10?

Comment: What's making these requests? Is there a way to do work on the results before returning them farther up the chain to other services?

Comment: @the-honorable-samuel-clemens 10 or fewer. I'm making the requests from a .NET Core 2.1 web service using Nest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

k, given the comments on the question, I am going to suggest an answer that is not exactly what you were looking for, but seems like a good thing to do in this situation.

Since we're only talking about 10 requests per query here, I suggest making multiple requests to elastic, but with one caveat: Do not make them in series, that's going to be less than ideal from a performance standpoint. In fact, do not bother excluding any IDs at all in the series of queries!

Make these requests asynchronously but request increasingly large pagesizes for each request. 10, 20, 30, 40, etc. Then in code, remove items from Block 1 in Block 2 and so on.
This way if "Block 2" has 100% overlap w/ block 1 then you are able to remove those 10 items and still have the required pagesize of 10 for Block 2.

Edit: Per @dotybear's comment: No need to make multiple requests, just increase the pagesize in each subsequent query (assuming that early "blocks" get priority for duplicates)

Comment: Pretty clever! Long as I don't have to make them in series I suppose I'm happy.

Comment: OR we could apply the same approach to our aggregate query, increasing subsequent block sizes by one whole page, instead of increasing the size of subsequent requests. I like this solution.

Comment: @dotybear I was looking at past answers since I bothered logging in to my account today and I remembered this one!  elasticsearch will consider every new aggregate as pretty much a  new request, so that means sending additional "aggregate blocks" in the same request will pretty much make several requests into potentially the same read replica, it actually might be more efficient to spread requests out if that is the case... I would want to verify before implenting this solution... 4 years ago :D

Answer (score 1):

one solution can be to create a negative query (of first one) for your second aggregation. So, if your query has must for some term, add must_not for same terms in your second query. It may not work for all use cases, But I guess it should be fine for above query.

Comment: Would you have to include the entire previous query in that second query as the exclude list in this case?  
Note to @dotybear : Seems straightforward when making two requests to Elastic, but trying to do it all in one might get silly (especially w/ this solution)

Comment: Yeah, I think it would be easier to send multiple requests, adding `must_not`s with ids from previous results, than to build one query this way (these are dynamically generated requests, with as many as 5-10 buckets).

Thank you for the idea!